# php loop through array objects and append the elements

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wts_id] => 47
            [wts_place_id] => 103
            [wts_start_date] => 2015-08-13
            [wts_end_date] => 2015-08-13
            [wts_start_time] => 12:00:00
            [wts_end_time] => 15:00:00
            [wts_day_off] => 0
            [wts_updated_on] => 2015-07-29 09:52:40
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wts_id] => 48
            [wts_place_id] => 103
            [wts_start_date] => 2015-08-13
            [wts_end_date] => 2015-08-13
            [wts_start_time] => 19:00:00
            [wts_end_time] => 22:00:00
            [wts_day_off] => 0
            [wts_updated_on] => 2015-07-29 09:53:00
        )

)
```

I need to append wts_start_Time and wts_end_time to a variable with || which differ each object element value.

Comment: Then go for it. (Where are you stuck? Show your code.)

Comment: So whats the issue over here.

Comment: I tried to do with for loop and got this way:
for($k=0; $k<count($query3); $k++){
    echo $time[$k] = $query3[$k]->wts_start_time."-".$query3[$k]->wts_end_time;
   }

Comment: So, I got the o/p: as 12:00-15:0019:00-22:00
But I need || between 12:00-15:00 and 19:00-22:00. where I can use that variable outside the for.

Comment: @user3378428 Don't post your code in the comments. Edit your question.

Comment: `echo implode('||', time);`

Answer (score 0):

This will create the array $time with  wts_start_Time-wts_end_time and join that array with "||"

```
for($k=0; $k<count($query3); $k++)
{ 
  $time[$k] = $query3[$k]->wts_start_time."-".$query3[$k]->wts_end_time;     
}
echo $final_value = implode("||", $time);
```